# Get a list of values of one column from the results of a query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a `User` model where users can have the same name.  I want to get the email addresses of all the users with a given name.  However, I have to do `result[0].email` on the result of the query to get just the email for a row.  I could do this with a for loop, but is there a way to just get the list of one field without having to do this every time?

```
my_result = db.session.query(my_table).filter_by(name=name)
emails = []
for r in my_result:
    emails.append(r.email)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, there's not really a way around the fact that SQLAlchemy queries return a list of dicts.  If you want a specific set of fields, you can query for just those fields, but if you want a list of *one* field, you'll have to extract it from the result.  The following example gets a list of the unique emails for every user with the given name.

```
emails = [r.email for r in db.session.query(my_table.c.email).filter_by(name=name).distinct()]
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a way to return specific columns from a `filter_by` query using the `values` method.  As follows:

```
 emails = [r[0] for r in db.session.query(my_table).filter_by(name=name).values('email')]
```

or:

```
 emails = [r[0] for r in User.query.filter_by(name=name).values('email')]
```

`values()` takes any number of field names as parameters and returns a generator that has tuples with each value from each field name.  Using a list comprehension to take the first item of that tuple `emails` will then be a list of plain string email addresses.

*Please note* that the `values` method is deprecated and you should use `with_only_columns` in the future.

Example to get only column `b`:

```
s = select(table1.c.a, table1.c.b)
s = s.with_only_columns(table1.c.b)
```

reference: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.with_only_columns

Comment: Please include documentation links when available. [Query.values()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.values) is deprecated in v2.0

Answer (score 1):

Just to keep a record, I like a wrapper with this function in my common use lib:

`def flat_list(l):
    return ["%s" % v for v in l]`

Then:

`flat_list(db.session.query(Model.column_attribute).all())`

Answer (score 0):

From the SQLAlchemy documentation for [Result.scalars()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.scalars):

```py
>>> result = conn.execute(text("select int_id from table"))
>>> result.scalars().all()
[1, 2, 3]
```